# How can I disable ALL notifications in OSX Lion?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I need to disable all notifications: iCal, Skype, and especially application updates. Everything.

I can find info on how to do this in Yosemite, but not Lion.

Would anyone know how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's make sure that we are talking about Mac OS X "Lion" which is version 10.7 and not "Mountain Lion" which is version 10.8. Is this correct? This is important since Notification Center debuted in 10.8.

If you are on 10.7 then I may suggest two workarounds.

**1.** You may want to install [Growl](http://growl.info/about) app and set all notifications off. Please, read [Help](http://growl.info/documentation.php) and [Blog](http://growlmac.tumblr.com/) sections before purchasing the app.

**2.** You may want to upgrade to "Mountain Lion" and then turn off all notifications by entering this commands in terminal:

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist
killall NotificationCenter
```

If you'll ever change your mind, you can then return it back by:

```
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist
```

Hope this helps.